# Adding a value to the first index of a list of array by using a list comprehension Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, list-comprehension

The Vals list comprehension below modifies `Values` such that for the number of nth rows it indexes the array values as such. How would I be able to add an increment to the `Vals` list comprehension where it adds 100 in front of all of the modified lists? I want to only modify  the list comprehension function to do that.

```
import numpy as np 

first_index_val = 100
Values = np.array([[130,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [130,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [130,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [130,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [130,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [130,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [130,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72]])

Vals = np.array([arr[i:] for i,arr in enumerate(Values.tolist())])
```

Output:

```
[list([130.0, 123.0, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
 list([123.0, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
 list([135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
 list([139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72]) list([156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
 list([163.88, 173.72]) list([173.72])]
```

Expected Output:

```
[list([100, 130.0, 123.0, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
 list([100, 123.0, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
 list([100, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
 list([100, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72]) list([100, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72])
 list([100, 163.88, 173.72]) list([100, 173.72])]
```

Comment: Just use `[100] + arr[i:]` in the list comprehension`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it, simple and declarative.

```
import numpy as np

first_index_val = 100
values = np.array([[130, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
               [130, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
               [130, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
               [130, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
               [130, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
               [130, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72],
               [130, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72]])

values = np.array([ [100] + arr[i:] for i, arr in enumerate(values.tolist())])
print(values)
```

Comment: use your enumeration after the last flip

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I still dont get the Expected Output when doing that. Even after the enumeration.

Comment: In that case, follow the solution posted by @Pepsi-Joe, only he misplaced the [100] it should be: np.array([ [100] + arr[i:] for i, arr in enumerate(values.tolist())])

Comment: I edited the code above to get the solution you want. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the addition to the list comprehension.

```
Vals = np.array([[100] + arr[i:] for i,arr in enumerate(Values.tolist())])
```

Comment: the functionality for this code does not work

Comment: Yes, it seems that Numpy is not happy with having rows of different lengths. Do you need it in an array? it seems you want a list of lists. If you are okay with a list of lists, then just get rid of np.array in my answer.